# How do you get a Subversion diff summary to ignore mergeinfo properties?

Tags: svn, merge, diff, mergeinfo

I have the Subversion 1.6.5 client and 1.5.4 server. And I mostly only care about diffs on fully repository paths, not working copies.

When diffing branches, ones that have been merged already show up as identical except for the [mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html) properties.

This is a touch annoying for a human who has to then look through the changes looking for anything that might be a real change.

However it's somewhat worse in our usecase as we have scripts that run around checking on the merge state of various things and the mergeinfo properties cause them to highlight a lot of things as being out of sync when they aren't.

Is there a way to get the diff summary to ignore the mergeinfo properties?

Answer (score 2):

In the end you have to use an appropriate external diff tool. If you don't care about property changes you can always use `filterdiff --clean` to remove files whose only changes are properties.